# Variable value not updating inside dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following simple dialog:

```
function confirmDialog(message, title) {


var returnvalue;

if ($("#confirmDialog").length == 0)
    $('body').append('<div id="confirmDialog"></div>');

var dlg = $("#confirmDialog")
    .html(message)
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        minHeight: 50,
        title: title,
        show: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 250
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 250
        },

        buttons: {
            "OK": {
                text: "OK",
                class: "",
                click: function () { returnvalue = true; $("#confirmDialog").dialog("close"); }
            },

            "Cancel": {
                text: "Cancel",
                class: "",
                click: function () { returnvalue = false; $("#confirmDialog").dialog("close"); }
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
$('#confirmDialog').dialog("open");
return returnvalue;
}
```

very simple implementation. My problem is that when I run through the script, at the end, when it returns the variable `returnvalue` is `undefined`, meaning, it did not set it to either `true` or `false` depending on which button was clicked.

I have tried setting it to `var returnvalue = false;` but it never gets a different value no matter which button I click.

Any help is appreciated!! Thank you!

EDIT:

I believe I noticed why the variable doesn't get set.  I am calling this dialog from the `click` event from another dialog, after the user clicks on the "Save" button of the parent dialog, this one pops up.  Now, since it is contained in a function, it does not wait for my input, meaning, it doesn't "see" that I clicked either "OK" or "Cancel".  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the button clicks trigger an event before they close the dialog, then I would listen for that event to happen in the parent process.

- parent dialog opens
- user clicks save
- opens confirmation dialog
- user closes confirmation dialog
- confirmation dialog triggers "ok" or "canceled" event depending
- parent dialog is listening for "ok" or "canceled" event
- parent dialog reacts accordingly

## confirmation dialog buttons

```
buttons: {
            "OK": {
                text: "OK",
                class: "",
                click: function () { $(this).trigger("ok"); $("#confirmDialog").dialog("close"); }
            },

            "Cancel": {
                text: "Cancel",
                class: "",
                click: function () { $(this).trigger("cancel"); $("#confirmDialog").dialog("close"); }
            }
        }
```

## parent dialog, or document.ready()

```
$("#confirmDialog").on({
    "ok":function(event,ui){ 
      //save work
    },
    "cancel":function(event,ui){
      // cancel work
     }
    },null,null);
```

Comment: the deferred stuff is great too!  I just didn't know if you were using the jqueryUI widget factory or not.

Comment: I will mark your answer as the solution because it does solve my problem. But it seems I will be going with the deferred method.  I appreciate your help man :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery dialogs do not block execution like the built in javascript `confirm()` function. I can suggest two possible solutions:

1. Pass "ok" and "cancel" callbacks into your `confirmDialog` function.
2. Have your `confirmDialog` function return a promise object that you resolve after a button is clicked and have the calling function wait for that to resolve.

I prefer option 2.

Comment: Can you point me into what specific property you're thinking of?  Deferred?

Comment: Yes, Deferred has a function called promise() that returns an object that works like a deferred but can't be resolved. In this case, you wouldn't want to allow the calling function to resolve the deferred. http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Comment: I will use this method since it seems far more elegant.  Thank you!